# Need top 1000 city names in Ukraine in English, Ukrainian, and Russian

Tags: data-request, geospatial, wikidata, translation, ukraine

I'm working on a project to track Russian troop movements in the Ukraine with a large group of people. I'm tasked with internationalizing the data.

We need a list of the top 1,000 cities in Ukraine and we need them in English, Ukrainian, and Russian. I'm hoping someone here can help me do this faster than if I were to learn it myself.

Right now I'm using https://query.wikidata.org/ because I think it has the ability to do this, but not having much luck.

Is there someone who can help me print a list of these names in 3 languages? One column per language?

Comment: Probably geonames https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/18467/1511

Comment: Or OSM https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/20238/1511

Comment: What are you looking for as "top"? WD only seems to have about 530 towns/cities/etc with a known population in Ukraine, so it might be tricky to go beyond that without using other sources

Comment: I would go with OSM Nominatim. Please have a look on example: https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/9882375. `name = Каменка` is in Ukrainian, `name:en`, `name:ru`, etc gives you the other languages. You have to define `top 1000`, for the population data you can check http://2001.ukrcensus.gov.ua/eng/results/general/

Answer (score 2):

The latest census in Ukraine was in 2001.  Results are published here: http://2001.ukrcensus.gov.ua and the data on cities are available here http://2001.ukrcensus.gov.ua/results/general/city/ including names.

UN Population Division publishes data on cities in World Urbanization Prospects  (https://population.un.org/wup/).  By a custom request they might provide more data on the cities.

UN Statistics Division (data.un.org) publishes data on cities here: City population by sex, city and city type
http://data.un.org/Data.aspx?d=POP&f=tableCode%3a240